# COUNT in WHERE loopback

Tags: strongloop, loopback

When I call my loopback API on the route `/models/?filter={"include":"c"}`, I get the following result :

```
[
{
"a": 1,
    "b": "abc",
    "c": [
      //
    ]
},
{
    "a": 2,
    "b": "def",
    "c": [
      //
    ]
},
{
    "a": 3,
    "b": "xyz",
    "c": [
      //
    ]
}
]
```

How can I get only the results where the "c" array is empty ? Basically I would like to reproduce a `WHERE COUNT(c) = 0` clause.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use LoopBack **Where** Filter: [Link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html)

Example :

```
/models/?filter={"where":{c: {$size: {$lt:0}}}
```